# xamarin.forms listview populate by BindingContext and viewmodel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new with Xamarin, but I'm coming from C# background.

I'm trying to set the items source of listview by passing viewmodel to the bindingcontext property. I know I can set the itemssoruce programatically in the code behind but I think setting it through the bindingcontext is the right way to do it, correct me if I'm wrong.

Let me start with what I have currently.

This is the viewmodel I have:

```
public class AirportSelectVM
{
    public int AirportID { get; set; }
    public string AirportICAO { get; set; }
    public int VolumeGallons { get; set; }
}
```

In the code behind I'm doing this:

```
private void SetInitialListView()
{
    ObservableCollection<AirportSelectVM> listAirport = new ObservableCollection<AirportSelectVM>();

    AirportSelectVM firstAirport = new AirportSelectVM();
    listAirport.Add(firstAirport);
    BindingContext = listAirport;
}
```

And in the XAML I have:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
                <Picker x:Name="pickerAircraft" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TailNumber}" SelectedItem="{Binding Id}" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerAircraft_SelectedIndexChanged" Title="Aircraft Selector"></Picker>

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listAirport}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10">
                                    <Label Text="Leg 1 Arrival" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Just for comparison the picker items source is set in the code behind but eventually I would like to move that in the bindingcontext as well.

So, my main question will be how to setup the items source of a listview through bindingcontext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the `BindingContext` of the `Page` to `listAirport`.  So the ItemsSource will be the same as the page binding

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
```

Comment: That is correct, will accept that in two minutes. Now if I want to add more items in the viewmodel, such as the picker items source I need to include the observable list for that control?

Comment: Yes, create a ViewModel class that contains the various lists/collections etc that are needed for the page

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it "the right way", you should learn more about the MVVM pattern.
For each page you are binding a page view model, which will be a bridge between your Models (data) and your UI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Now if you just want to have a working code, you need to set your `ItemsSource` directly like this:

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
                <Picker x:Name="pickerAircraft" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TailNumber}" SelectedItem="{Binding Id}" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerAircraft_SelectedIndexChanged" Title="Aircraft Selector"></Picker>

                <ListView x:Name="AirportListView">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10">
                                    <Label Text="Leg 1 Arrival" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

code-behind:

```cs
private void SetInitialListView()
        {
            ObservableCollection<AirportSelectVM> listAirport = new ObservableCollection<AirportSelectVM>();

            AirportSelectVM firstAirport = new AirportSelectVM();
            listAirport.Add(firstAirport);
            AirportListView.ItemsSource = listAirport;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the details @Roubachof, will upvote your answer for the details but I was trying to bind the controls through bindingcontext, something I achieved with the other answer.